# make Li width to not be affected by its ul children

Tags: css, html-lists

this styling bit is proving my patience a lot.
The html structure being

```
<li><a>HeaderLink</a>
<ul><li>content</li><li>content</li></ul>
</li>
```

I am trying to mimic this navigation : http://www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/pages/#top
but cannot see what they do so the higher li width does not get affected by the width of its ul children.

Please Help!!! Thank you!

Comment: Part of your HTML is missing.  Please give complete code and some CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is

Parent li `{position:relative}`

li ul `{white-space:nowrap;position:absolute;top:100%;left:...}`

Try this. Next time, provide your code!

Answer (score 0):

They are setting a width on the child UL.

If you are looking to make this responsive by using percentages, you will have a harder time, but just setting your code like this should solve your problem:

```
li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    // more styles here
}
li ul {
    position:absolute;
    width: #px;
    // more styles here
}
```